# document database with search features

Tags: c#, search, mongodb, ravendb, document-database

Does anybody know if any of the document databases offers good search features? I see RavenDb is using Lucene.net to some degree but I am looking for a more integrated search experience like the Truffler.net client api are giving you. They have built a .net client on top of Elasticsearch which gives great search features.

I think it would be a killer feature if any of the document database clients could offer similar features directly through their client api but I am not sure if that is even feasible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TT,
RavenDB is providing a lot of searching capabilities. It is deeply integrated into to API.
You can do simple and full text searches, suggestions, spatial, and a lot more.
Here is an example of how you can do the same query that they have in the main page:

```
session.Query<Resturant, Resturants_Search>()
  .Customize(c=>c.WithinRadiusOf(radios: 3, latitude: 51, longitude: 43)
  .Search(r=>r.Query, "Seafood")
  .Select(r=>new{r.Name, r.Address})
  .Take(5);
```

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware you had these kind of abilities. I'll give raven a try, at least now that its available on appharbor. I do like Truffler's programming interface a lot but it feels kind of akward having much of the same data in 2 different datastores when its not really necessary.

Comment: RavenDB is a good choice. I used both as Document Store Server and Embedded Document Store.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) or CouchDB? I know some of the big guys like ShutterFly, Craigs List, etc use MongoDB. There are several api's, including one for C#.

Comment: I have been using MongoDb for a while. They have some full text search capability but not not anything advanced as far as I know. Also I am not sure if any of this is usable through the C# driver.